# Textbox opacity not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to set up a `Grid` that contains 2 controls. One is a `Canvas` that has an image for its background, and one is a `TextBox` that is overtop of part of the canvas.

My issue is that part of the image that the `Canvas` uses as its background has lines that I am trying to completely cover up with the textbox. Even when I set the textbox's opacity to 100%, you can still see through it and see the lines behind it, as shown (the light gray lines are the black lines I am trying to cover with the textbox):

[image]

As I said, I have the opacity of the textbox set to 100% but this still happens. Heres my XAML:

```
  <Grid x:Name="PriorGrid" Height="1173" Width="715">
        <Canvas x:Name="DrawingCanvas">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/prior.png"/>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
        <TextBox x:Name="PriorNoteTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,762,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="228" Width="695" Opacity="100"/>
    </Grid>
```

What would cause this?

Comment: Well it works fine on my machine, and if you want a completely opaque object you don't need to set opacity.

Comment: You may have to change the background color of the textbox. You may have it set to transparent which usually sets it to the background image of the main control. Change the color to "Control" or maybe white.

Comment: @user2357446 Do you have some implicit style that changes `TextBox` template? If yes show it in your question. Also [`Opacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0

Answer (score 1):

it works fine on my machine, just check if you are not setting background of your textbox to transparent somewhere or else just add image control to your grid and place text box over it. like this

```
 <Grid x:Name="PriorGrid">
    <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="C:\Users\malhom\Pictures\Bart.png"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="PriorNoteTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```